# How to ignore mongo when start application

Tags: spring-boot

A legacy Spring boot project, before it used mongo, but now it does not need. Now start this project it has this error

```
2022-10-27 14:10:13.119 [cluster-ClusterId{value='635a20bb714f8f71e2e5d041', description='null'}-10.48.51.21:40010] [INFO] [org.mongodb.driver.cluster] - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 10.48.51.21:40010
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

then I exclude related `Auto Configuration` class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

but this time project start failed

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field mongoTemplate in com.bxt.bmht_support.dao.BmhtMideTableDao required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' that could not be found.
```

How to disable mongo without update current code? just want ignore it.

Comment: I think, you cannot have this: you have to remove all runtime dependencies (mongo repositories) .i.e. "update code".

Comment: You have code such as `BmhtMideTableDao` that depend on Mongo-related beans (such as `MongoTemplate`). What do you want to happen to those?

Comment: I just want project could started successfully and not to connect mongo db during runtime.